# SSAS - Movement between from and two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have a very specific problem on calculating movement using two dates from and to in cube and details are as follows:

**Product group**, **sub group** and **asset** and **liability** are *derived* using client type, *product type* and *closing balance* being in *credit* or *debit* on a **particular day**.

**Product group**, **sub group** and **asset/liability** *can be selected* from a dimension which has a surrogate key that is stored in the fact table against the date key and account key.
Fact table is *"account's daily snapshot"* which has every day's data starting from the date account was opened till today and the granularity is **DateKey** and **AccountKey**.

Consider the scenario that on 15th Jan a particular account was categorised as **"Asset"** based on associated product type, client type and closing balance value but on the 31st because of the movements after 15th till 31st; it went into **"Liability"**. Now consider that the user would like to see the movements between these two dates and selects **"from"** and **"to"** dates in the cube using two date hierarchies.

The **"to" date** hierarchy runs on a date hierarchy where as **"from" date** hierarchy is dependent on floating date dimension that does not have any relationship and used with linked member function to get the starting point to perform the sum on "to" date hierarchy.

Now when issuing the two dates 15th and 31st on the cube; behind the scene data *from 15th till 31st* comes in scope of the selection which has key for asset and liability attribute values.

So when the user choose to show *dimension attributes Product group*, *sub group and asset/liability* the cube shows *values against attribute values* **"Asset"** and **"Liability"** which is correct on two rows.
Users would like to see that the asset or liability should be from the "to" date only but should also be able to pass from date to get the sum of movement.
We are wondering if we can keep the closing balance from **"to" date** and show Product group, sub group and asset/liability dimension attributes using this closing balance and using **"from"** date just to calculate the *sum* of movements but not to have impact on Product group, sub group and asset/liability attribute values and subtract it from closing balance to get the desired result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add table definitions. Also some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. What have you tried? Show us your current attempts! Read this too https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh boy... Do you know what TL;DR means? Any piece of code would help more

Comment: Apologies guys, Can't see the delete button. I have reposted the formatted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148748/ssas-range-of-dates-issue